# Coordinates transformation of four columns in qgis

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have four columns with grid coordinates X_min Y_min X_max Y_max. As these coordinates are in ESPG 3857, i want to convert each of the columns to 4326 in QGIS.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the field calculator to

1) build a point with the min (or max) coordinates

2) change its projection

3) extract its X (or Y) coordinate

4) save it

You would have to create 4 fields, with the following values:

```
x(transform( make_point(x_min, y_min ),'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326'))
y(transform( make_point(x_min, y_min ),'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326'))
x(transform( make_point(x_max, y_max ),'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326'))
y(transform( make_point(x_max, y_max ),'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326'))
```